# Connecting SQL Server Database to Dbase Database

Tags: sql-server, dbase

What is the best way to use SQL to communicate with DBase?

I basically need to do a select statement on the dbase database and get info off it as well as push info to it. Please help.

Im using `SQL Server 2012`

Comment: Do you want to "communicate" dBase and MS SQL Server, or you just need to execute an SQL query on your dBase DB?

Comment: I need to communicate them. Will need to check fields on the dbase side and also receive/add info from/to the dbase

Comment: I think you cannot communicate them. The only way is to export dBase data to SQL Server, do the work you want, then export back to dBase. Or vice versa: SQL Serever -> dBase table(s) -> SQl Server.

Comment: What about a webservice that will send and get info from the dbase database and then use that info to connect and talk to the SQL database? Do you think this will work?

Comment: I don't konw such services...